# How to upload existing file in text/doc format using driveitem object microsoft graph API in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-graph-api

I am creating a web application and I want to upload the existing file from my drive to onedrive folder which I have created pro-grammatically. I have followed the upload example from the  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs), but I was unable to create the file and and upload the existing file content in it, although I am able to create the folder using driveitem object.

```
        DriveItem file = new DriveItem()
        {
            File = new Microsoft.Graph.File(),
            Name = "abc.txt",                              
        };
        var freq = graphClient
                .Me
                .Drive
                .Items[parentFolder.Id]                    
                .Request();
              byte[] data = 
        System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Desktop\testfile.txt");
        DriveItem uploadedFile = null; MemoryStream stream = null;
        using (stream = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            file.Content = stream;
            stream.Position = 0;                
        }
        var req = graphClient
               .Me                 
              .Drive.Items[parentFolder.Id]            
               .Content
               .Request();
        try
        {
            uploadedFile = await req.PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

But this code is not creating file and not updating the content in the file which I am creating using driveitem object.

Answer (score 0):

The following endpoint demonstrates how to replace an existing file:

```
PUT /me/drive/items/{item-id}:/{path-to-file}/content
```

where `item-id` refers to a `DriveItem` with a folder facet

**C# example**

```
var path = @"C:\Sample.docx";

var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

var driveItem = await graphClient.Me
      .Drive
      .Items[folderItemId]
      .ItemWithPath(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path))
      .Content
      .Request()
      .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
```